# Windows Store Apps: How to implement credit card payments

Tags: security, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, payment-gateway

I'm developing a windows store app that includes a module where app users will be able to pay bills from the app using their credit cards.

would you please recommend a technique to implement such a feature securely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother implementing this myself. Not because there's no way to pull it off but because of one single reason: **Fraud**.

It took banks and clearing houses years to get this straight. Don't reinvent the wheel and go for an established solution like Paypal or Amazon Payments.

Comment: I believe using Paypal or Amazon is the optimal solution, otherwise using a webview to process the process through the website is not a bad solution either

Answer (score 1):

Open a `webview` having credit card form over `https` and use `Stripe` or `Paypal` or `Braintree` or `Amazon Payments` to process the cc info.